# Check if div has image on slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, html5-video, slideshow

I have a simple slideshow.

I want to check if slide is image or video. If is video play it and when video ends autoplay slider.

Now. I'm using Snook's slider.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><img></li>
    <li><video></li>
    <li><img></li>
    <li><video></li>
    <li><img></li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
function startSlider(duration){
    setInterval(function() { 
        jQuery('#slideshow > li:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#slideshow');
    }, duration);
}
    if (jQuery("#slideshow li").has('img') == true) {
        startSlider(4000);


     }else{
      myVideoPlayer.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {

        var ddur =  Math.round(myVideoPlayer.duration) * 1000;
        console.log(ddur);
        startSlider(ddur);
        });
    }
```

But when next slide changes it keeps same duration as video. How to check if has video get duration and set it else set duration to 4000?

Thanks.

Update: http://jsfiddle.net/nbK2S/1/

Comment: The way you have it set up now it will be running multiple startSlider functions if there are images. You need to put the if/else inside the setinterval approximately around the `.next` part to where it checks if the next object is an image or video and sets the rules depending on what it receives

Comment: I'd say use the fadeIn() callback

Comment: If you provide a jsFiddle or something similar we can help you with the implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing what you asked to do, changing the interval time depending on whether or not it's a video, can by done this way:

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
var intervalTime = 3000;

function runInterval () {
    if($('#slideshow > div:first').next().has('img').length == 0)
    {
        intervalTime = Math.round($('video').attr('duration') * 1000);
        clearInterval(s);
        s = setInterval(runInterval, intervalTime);        
    }
    else {
        if(intervalTime != 3000)
        {
            intervalTime = 3000;
            clearInterval(s);
            s = setInterval(runInterval, intervalTime);
        }
    }
    $('#slideshow > div:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)        
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#slideshow');
}

var s = setInterval(runInterval, intervalTime);
```

[Here's the fiddle for that](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/nbK2S/2/)

However I'd recommend only stopping the interval if the video is paused instead to reduce errors and allow users more control. That can be done this way:

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
var intervalTime = 3000;

function runInterval() {
    $('#slideshow > div:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#slideshow');
}

var s = setInterval(runInterval, intervalTime);

$('video:eq(0)').bind('play', function () {
    clearInterval(s);
    $('video:eq(0)').attr('duration', '7')
    alert($('video:eq(0)').attr('duration'));
});

$('video:eq(0)').bind('pause ended', function () {
     s = setInterval(runInterval, intervalTime);
});
```

And [here is that Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/nbK2S/3/). This also prevents some possible errors with the video being cut off or playing before it should (the first time I opened your jsfiddle I was looking at a different page and didn't know where the sound was coming from - this prevents that from happening)

**NOTE** These solutions are made to work only if there is 1 or 0 videos. The code would have to be edited a little to suit more

Comment: Thats awesome, I went with first solution, since is more familiar to me. When it is video, first I clearInterval, Play video, get duration, set interval. This way I get duration without checking for metadata. Also works if slider have more than one video :). First solution is better because I dont want to allow controls to user, more like scotch-soda.com